# How to set SSL Cookie asp IIS6 ASP

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-6

We have recentlly had a pen test doe on one of our application.

The only vunerablility was "SSL Cookie Not Used"

I know I need to use AspKeepSessionIDSecure, but how do i set this?

I've found this tool that allows you to amend the value
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=56fc92ee-a71a-4c73-b628-ade629c89499&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this tool that allows you to amend the value http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=56fc92ee-a71a-4c73-b628-ade629c89499&displaylang=en